# Allure при команде allure open открывает пустую страницу браузера

Tags: веб-сервер, allure

Выполняю allure open, получаю следующий результат, в чём может быть дело?

[image: веб-сервер]

Answer (score 0):

Был русский символ в пути. Проблема решена.